# What is the most suitable function for a heart?

Tags: education, graphing-functions

I have seen some codes to plot heart on matlab, e.g.

1. [first example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23972-chebfun/content/chebfun/examples/fun/html/ValentinesDay.html?s_eid=PSM_3462)
2. [second example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18754?s_eid=PSM_3403)

How can I prove/find from the theory how to plot a perfect heart?

---

[image]

Comment: Is there any theory of "heart perfectness"? Because I believe that is still subjective matter of taste.

Comment: Heart perfectness is a subject that can beat to death.

Comment: MathWorld has a few more: [heart curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html), [heart surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartSurface.html). Unfortunately for you, none of them are perfect (whatever that means).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a "perfect" heart should look something like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/Wiki_Heart_Antomy_Ties_van_Brussel.jpg). I mean that's what I've been told anyway. I haven't really seen a (human) heart myself. Second, how much "complexity" or "simplicity" are you looking for in the equations? No matter what (digital) representation you give (any picture of a heart for example), it can easily be parametrized and represented by scores of equations. An example, give me any curve in 2D and I can split the curve up into little sections, do fourier analysis on each section, parametrize them and combine them together using step functions and then just plot them which is exactly what Wolfram people did [here with Cupid](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cupid%20curve). The equations fill six pages but hey it is a pretty good picture of cupid, no!

;-) So the smarty pants answer to your question is you give me a 2D/3D picture of whatever you think is a perfect heart and I will give you the equations describing it.

There is also [this in 2D](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=heart%20curve&a=%2aC.heart%20curve-_%2aPlaneCurveClass-&a=%2aDPClash.PlaneCurveE.heart%20curve-_%2aCardioid.dflt-) and [this in 3D](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EquationsForValentines/) which is probably what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

Well I think a perfekt heart is one which beats, and your question has no correct answer. A real heart doesn't look like those plotted ones and anyway I like them in 2d not in 3d.

Comment: And without any cholesterol clogging up the arteries...according to my doctor anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For a 2-dimensional curve, try Paul Ma's Heart Equation
$$(y - a|x|^b)^2 + (cx)^2 = d$$
Where   a b c d   are parameters that you can set.

In my light-hearted blog on heart curves ==>
http://onemanadreaming.blogspot.com.au/2014/08/mathematical-equation-of-love-heart.html

There are some sample values for  a b c d.  You can try out other values, then choose the most perfect heart curve that suits your fancy.

Would love to see you post here the best set of values you have picked.   :-)